# setting fontLigatures: true in VS Code doesn't change the ligatures

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the JetBrains Mono font in my VS Code, and everything is working correctly except for fontLigatures. I have it set:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "'JetBrainsMonoNL-Medium', 'FiraCode'",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontSize": 13,
  "editor.fontWeight": "300",
  "editor.letterSpacing": 1.2,
  "editor.lineHeight": 22,
```

but for some reason it still won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains Mono comes in two versions JetBrains Mono and Jet Brains Mono NL the NL stands for No Ligatures, which of course was the problem.